# ListView - Unable to group items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to group ListView items (2 per row) but I can't make it work. This is what I am using:

```
<asp:ListView ID="BookListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="BookListView_SelectedIndexChanged" GroupItemCount="2">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
             <div ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">

             </div>
             <div  style="text-align:center" runat="server">
                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                    ...........
                </asp:DataPager>
             </div>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <GroupTemplate>
            <div ID="itemPlaceholder" class="GroupTemplateContainerDiv" runat="server" style="clear:both">
            </div>
    </GroupTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="ItemTemplateContainerDiv">
            <div class="itemTemplateleftColumn">
                ..........
            </div>
            <div class="itemTemplaterightColumn">
                ..........  
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Everything works fine except from the grouping part. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `PlaceHolder` instead of divs:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div>
         <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder" />

         <div  style="text-align:center" runat="server">
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                ...........
            </asp:DataPager>
         </div>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>

<GroupTemplate>
        <div class="GroupTemplateContainerDiv" style="clear:both">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        </div>
</GroupTemplate>
```

Comment: Are any items showing on the page? It's not something wrong with your CSS or anything like that? Might as well cover all bases =]

Comment: All the items show up and their layout is as intended but each one shows below the previous.

Comment: Ok so in the markup do you have multiple occurrences of `<div class="GroupTemplateContainerDiv">`?

Comment: Yes I do. 2 items in each group <div> so I guess the problem is probably in the CSS....

Comment: Thanks for your help, found the problem in the Css. I'm marking it as an answer since I would be looking in the wrong place forever if it weren't for your question :)

Comment: Excellent, glad you found it ^_^